# Triangulating Angles

Tags: code-golf, geometry

**Prompt:**

You are given two sets of XY coordinates along with two angles (all are floats): `X1 Y1 A1 X2 Y2 A2`. The angles are relative to world coordinates: 0 being straight up or north and going clockwise.

Your program or function has to return a set of two floats of the XY coordinates the two angles cross at.

**Example:**

[image: Picture of problem example in GeoGebra]

In this case, the resulting point is between the two inputted points. For the case `100 500 50 300 600 80` (using degrees), the correct answer is `198 582`. Online representation [here](https://www.geogebra.org/calculator/jxqegd4x)

Other examples of edge cases:
`1 1 45 4 4 45` returns `NULL`
`1 4 45 2 4 45` returns `NULL`
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlmQO.jpg

**Rules:**

- Angles can be in radians or in degrees
- The program should have a separate answer if there is not a valid answer: if the two lines are parallel (zero solutions) or the same line (infinitely many solutions)
- The value returned can be represented in any form: `198;582`, `198 582` and `198_582` are all valid
- The answer can be rounded to a full number
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! I'd recommend using the [sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges) for future challenges, although this seems pretty good compared to a lot of first challenges we get :p. As an aside, I'd recommend not allowing rounding to the nearest full number, as you require using floats.

Comment: For challenges like this it is most unusual to have to handle input errors, suggest assuming only one point of intersection and answers may do anything if there isn't. .

Comment: Please add test cases in the text, not with an external link

Comment: @LuisMendo Especially an external link to *images*!

Comment: @UnrelatedString Well said :-)

Comment: @LuisMendo thanks for the tip! Fixed

Comment: If I did my math correctly, the result for your example is approximately `(197.672, 581.957)`, or `(198, 582)` if rounded.

Comment: Please note that [you should not make assumptions about language features](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8067/58563). In many languages, `NULL` doesn't mean anything. This is one of the reasons why it's recommended to allow very flexible I/O.

Comment: Even if the problems with this challenge are fixed, it doesn't see very interesting in my view. The shortest approach in most languages is going to be to implement a mathematical formula (see Arnauld's answer for example), so the challenge boils down to "find the formula", which in this case, isn't very interesting

Comment: I think that's a very decent first attempt at writing a challenge nonetheless and I hope we'll see more challenges from you soon. As said previously, don't hesitate to use [our sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges) to get feedback before posting to main. The sandbox is not perfect and it may take some time. But most obvious problems are usually caught early.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 76 bytes

Expects the angles in radians. Returns either `[x,y]` or `0` if the lines are parallel or coincident.

```javascript
(x,y,a,X,Y,A)=>a-A&&[(m=(t=Math.tan)(a))*(X-=(x-=m*y)+t(A)*Y,X/=m-t(A))+x,X]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYxLC4JAFIX3/YpZyb3jHR9l4WYCly2CliPRYjDtgY/IIfTXm5aL0OBwuJzvnnPXL10nz9vDiLI6p10mO2ioJU2KYopQbrWILOsIhQQj99pcHaNLBI3IQQkJjZAFb9E2ECGPSbmyEMONdkPq1CVVWVd56uTVBTLwPY/Y@mvMZX7oMc4@o4cdsdUANoOFM4q4mEwR6zXS/jugUT/Rv1IwKS3npe4N)

Or [**71 bytes**](https://tio.run/##bYw7D4JAEIR7f8WVu7DHQ9HQnAmlhYnlEWNxQfAR4IxcDPz6E5TCgMlksplvZ@7qpZrseXsYXutzbgthoaWOFElKKUGxPUIlwIi9MlfPqBpBIToguYCWi8rp0DWQoJOS9EXFhxvdluTJZrpudJl7pb5AAWEQEFt/jfksjAPmsM/oYUdsNYDNYPGMIi4mU8R6jbT/jmjUT/SvFE1Ky3nJvgE) if we can just return `[Infinity,Infinity]` for invalid inputs.

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <sup><s>131</s> \$\cdots\$ <s>106</s></sup> 104 bytes

Saved 9 bytes thanks to [Arnauld](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58563/arnauld)!!!
Saved <s>4</s> a whopping 15 bytes thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)!!!

```c
#define f(x,y,a,X,Y,A)float M=tan(A),m=tan(a),n;printf(a-A?"%f,%f":"0",(n-Y)*M+X,n=(M*Y-m*y-X+x)/(M-m));
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ddJBT8IwFAfwO5@iqSFpx2vYhhhgTkOMBw8kHCFiTFNaXGTFsCW2Gr66cxSG0@Gh6dpf8@/bSwVbCVEUF0upEi2RIgYscJjBHMZUrTc8R5M455qMKaTug1PQ0ds20bkinI1vcVtBW@ER9jEQzebUm3RmoGMy8eYs9SybdQztkglLKY1OF00fEBebjLCAtlKeaEI/W@hwXy6zPHs2weNT/Bn4PpRjF/1G67BfYr@J/Ije9KEbDHwop8u/Z0y4P9MrA3pn0h1elXh1Jt3h4J90ad6kyOXy2bjqhwPwz6B1BQ7CA4oXvvXEixSvcrsHvDD34cIM78rRx1Bf9rBL22xJ2X6U6KU0sR@5@TpLPuRG1SroHna8n52o03Fn970@1mSC@NRvZ0/RyWxltmm8Mt40E8anLjcyK7NN45XxppU/WuttQ21ca@6PHp8pJu6N0m5boRmqLdgNIhhMADYAHoAJwYbAQ@qSyfn9KpOie3dlolejKnOhMUgD0u5P7lq74kuoNV9lBVunBXv/Bg)

Either prints the intersection as `%f,%f` or `0` if the lines are parallel or coincident.

Comment: I suppose [something like that](https://tio.run/##HcbBCoJAEADQe1@xbAgzNkOdWyT8gL2KHofNdQV3ixJSxF9vg97pOR6cy/l47/2YetWohVYSaqmjmiJZCgcPDfrpIbNqzBarWRIIGvtPjSZUALbsOJYrMrS8IJ7BckTzfI1p9iBc33ThqfD6qi@aIHCHpT21FNDsOcqYANW256/zkwzvzFPM/PkB) would be acceptable.

Comment: @Arnauld Interesting, thought I had to avoid a divide-by-zero crash - thanks! :D

Comment: Yeah, `1/0` would core dump but both `0.0/0.0` and `1.0/0.0` are fine for gcc. So you should be OK. :-)